# Looking for Ars Combinatoria 42 (1996)

Tags: reference-request

I'm doing my BSc thesis and am looking for a paper by Yair Caro, "Simple proofs to three parity theorems". I can't find anything online, so I'm looking for the next best thing, the whole book(?) of Ars Combinatoria 42 (1996) and can find nothing too. Does anyone know how to our hands on either one of those?

I tried the webpage of Ars Combinatoria, and found the paper, but there were no options to download the paper.

Comment: I did do some searching. The best I could find I'm sorry to say are these lecture notes from Richard Stanley, which *uses* the result.  

https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf  Tracking down the paper itself that you are looking for does appear challenging. You could always try emailing the author.....

Comment: There might be a print version in a library near you.  [Here's](https://www.worldcat.org/title/ars-combinatoria-a-canadian-journal-of-combinatorics/) Worldcat's list of libraries that hold issues of the journal.  If none of them are close enough for you to get physical access, you might nevertheless be able get the relevant volume through an interlibrary loan, or a photocopy of the article through an interlibrary copy request.

Comment: You can try requesting a scanned copy from the author. You can find an email address in this recent preprint for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.01088.pdf

Comment: @Gary and and Mike, I tried contacting Caro, unfortunately he doesnt have it either. I will try the public libraries in Budapest next. Should I do something with the paper if I found it? Post it online or something like that

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes You may try contacting the Alfréd Rényi Institute in Budapest. They have the largest mathematical library in the country. I would not submit the paper online due to copyright issues.

Comment: @Gary, guys, as an update, Alfred Renyi's library does have a copy of the whole journal.